Borrow checking for C struct field
Imagine that C API exposes opaque pointer to some data and two accessors to some field void set_string(struct foo*, const char*) and  const char* get_string(struct foo*) and that documentation states something along the lines

The string returned by get_string is valid as long as the opaque pointer to foo is valid and no subsequent set_string call is made. Otherwise behavior is undefined

This is simple example of the header from C that exemplifies the issue
//foo.h
struct foo;
const char* get_string(struct foo*);
void set_string(struct foo*, const char*);

I'm wondering if and how is it possible to make rust borrow checker keep an eye on that external reference and avoid potential UB after generating bindings with bindgen. I have been experimenting around with
use foo::foo;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<'a> {
    pointer: *const foo,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a CStr>,
}

but it seems to be a dead end.

You can wrap up the unsafe calls to the extern C functions in a safe API that you expose to your Rust code: example.

struct foo* in C is equivalent to *mut foo in Rust, not *const foo

One worry is that you didn't provide documentation for the ownership of the const char* given to set_string. Is it just a "reference" and it allocates a copy internally? Or does the function "claim ownership" of the string data? If so how does it free it? Hopefully more of the documentation says since that will affect how exactly to provide that safe interface, but that is largely tangential to how to handle the lifetimes.

So the documentation essentially tells you the value returned by get_string is borrowed from struct foo and set_string mutates it so needs a mutable borrow, you can do that without any lifetime in struct Foo on the Rust side, just wrap the calls to set|get_string in safe, abstracting methods:
// creating a module to contain the code that needs to be checked for soundness
mod foo_mod {
    use std::ffi::{c_char, CString, CStr};
    struct foo;
    pub struct Foo {
        // musn't be `pub`
        pointer: *mut foo,
    }
    impl Foo {
        pub fn set_string(&mut self, s: CString) {
            extern "C" {
                fn set_string(this: *mut foo, s: *const c_char);
            }
            // SAFETY:
            // this is safe assuming:
            // - `self.pointer` is always a valid pointer to a `struct foo`
            // - `set_string` in C does not deallocate `s` (unless by leveraging the appropriate Rust code to do so)
            unsafe { set_string(self.pointer, s.into_raw()) }
        }
        pub fn get_string(&self) -> &CStr {
            extern "C" {
                fn get_string(this: *mut foo) -> *const c_char;
            }
            // SAFETY:
            // this is safe assuming:
            // - `self.pointer` is always a valid pointer to a `struct foo`
            // - `char* get_string()` always returns a valid C string given a valid `struct foo` pointer
            unsafe {
                let ptr = get_string(self.pointer);
                CStr::from_ptr(ptr)
            }
        }
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            // this or any constructors must make sure to only create `Foo`s that contain a valid `pointer`
            todo!()
        }
    }
}

Playground

Note: Foo::set_string in Rust is safe under the stated assumptions, but it leaks the passed in CString everytime you use it. In a production environment that's unlikely what you want, but properly dealing with it depends on how Cs set_string expects the string to be passed as kmdreko notes.
